Male USB C to Male USB A 2.0
So I have this Macbook USB hub thing that I got at a returned merchandise shop for $2. It works.
However, it uses a male USB C connector, but most of my devices DON'T have USB C.
I've tried soldering a chopped up phone cord in place of that USB C connector, but the blasted thing STILL won't show up.
Am I missing something?

Yes, obviously, but we don't know what. You generally can't chop off a Type-C plug of a sophisticated USB hub/docking station, splice the 5 to 10 GBPS high speed data wires together on a Type-A plug and expect it to work. Mind telling details or showing photos what kind of device it was and how you tried to connect the wires? Also Type-C connectors are termed plugs and receptacles. You likely had a Type-C plug and replaced with Type-A plug. How many wires you connected?

It really depends what the USB C connection is doing,  if it's PCIe over thunderbolt that's not going to work over a USB A connector.

I didn't think USB3.2 supported PCIe. Do you mean USB4 or Thunderbolt instead? Anyway, the used connector according to OP was USB2.

I am suspecting that. While the hub does connect to the two Android phones with USB C I have, the controller in it might only accept USB 3.
